# Replace column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

how can I replace the lieferanten_nr (from artikel) with the name (from lieferanten) without subselects and joins?

I have to identify the name of the lieferanten and replace the lieferanten_nr from artikel by the name.

1.Table

```
select bezeichnung, lieferanten_nr from artikel;
```

2.Table

```
select lieferanten_nr, name from lieferanten;
```

[image]

instead of lieferanten_nr there have to be the name

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: provide some example. do you mean updating values??

Comment: `without subselects and joins` - you cannot. You need to join the two tables in some way either by a join or by a correlated sub-query.

Comment: but there have to be a way. its the task

Comment: is lieferanten_nr unique in both the artikel and lieferanten tables? Also, what are the exact details of the task?

Comment: lieferanten_nr are the same in both tables. I have to take the 'name' from lieferanten and replace 'lieferanten_nr' from artikel with it.

Comment: 'replace' where, in the result of a query? What exactly is the task asking you to do? And what have you been learning about - maybe you're expected to use cursor loops or collections or something, but we can't guess what your tutor is expecting you to know or attempt.

Comment: And is that column unique in both tables?

Comment: instead of lieferanten_nr there have to be the name

Comment: Please show the source tables as formatted text not images; and also show the output you want, also as text. If it isn't what MTO's query produces then you haven't explained what you want properly.

Answer (score 2):

Given the artificial restrictions of no joins or sub-queries this is about the closest I could get using `UNION` (and assuming that no sub-queries means no correlated sub-queries):

```
SELECT bezeichnung,
       name
FROM   (
  SELECT bezeichnung,
         LEAD( name ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY lieferanten_nr
                                          ORDER BY name NULLS FIRST ) AS name
  FROM   (
    SELECT lieferanten_nr,
           bezeichnung,
           NULL AS name
    FROM   artikel
    UNION ALL
    SELECT lieferanten_nr,
           NULL,
           name
    FROM   lieferanten
  )
)
WHERE  bezeichnung IS NOT NULL
AND    name        IS NOT NULL;
```

If you ignore the restriction of no joins then it becomes very simple:

```
select a.bezeichnung,
       l.name
from   artikel a
       INNER JOIN
       lieferanten l
       ON ( a.lieferanten_nr = l.lieferanten_nr );
```

Comment: As I said, I took the view that it was disallowing correlated sub-queries otherwise you start disallowing everything and the answer to the question ends up being "its not possible".

Comment: @HansBaum How does it not work?

Comment: do you see the graphic? It have ot be like the graphic

Comment: @HansBaum - the graphic doesn't show the output you want. This query gives you the bezeichnung and name, which is what you asked for, and what the graphic also suggests you want. Why isn't this working for you? What is wrong with what it produces?